# linq query not returning anything by itself but data shows when there is a join added. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core-3.1

No idea how to troubleshoot this but returns nothing even though there is data in the table

```
  var quickLinks = from ql in _ctx.QuickLinks
                             
                             select new QuickLinksViewModel
                             {                                    
                                 ItemId = ql.ItemID,
                                 ItemGuid = ql.ItemGUID,
                                 UserId = ql.UserId,
                                 Computerid = ql.Computerid,
                                 Docid = ql.Docid,
                                 CustomLinkUrl = ql.CustomLinkUrl,
                                 CustomLinkText = ql.CustomLinkText,
                                 LinkOrder = ql.LinkOrder,
                                 CustomLinkTarget = ql.CustomLinkTarget                                     
                             };
       return quickLinks;
```

but when I add this join it pulls the data

```
  var quickLinks = from ql in _ctx.QuickLinks
                             join cd in _ctx.CMSDocument
                             on ql.Docid equals cd.DocumentID                                 
                             select new QuickLinksViewModel
                             {                                     
                                 ItemId = ql.ItemID,
                                 ItemGuid = ql.ItemGUID,
                                 UserId = ql.UserId,
                                 Computerid = ql.Computerid,
                                 Docid = ql.Docid,
                                 CustomLinkUrl = ql.CustomLinkUrl,
                                 CustomLinkText = ql.CustomLinkText,
                                 LinkOrder = ql.LinkOrder,
                                 CustomLinkTarget = ql.CustomLinkTarget                                     
                             };
       return quickLinks;
```

where am I going wrong?

Comment: What returns in both cases?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. If you want a list, put `ToList()` on the end of your `select{ }`

Comment: Sorry, I started to write a comment but when I hit return to add a new line it messed up.  It wasn't the type of item that it was returning that was the issue. The problem that i was running into, was the call was getting any data on the first example, but for some reason once I added the join it returned data.  The reason was because in my quicklinks entity I had an int that could be nullable but was not defined as nullable.  Once I fixed that, the first query started to work.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.  The issue was I had an int in my entity that was not defined as nullable.

```
public Nullable<int> DocId { get; set; }
```